# Egit ignores files from playframework

Tags: git, playframework, egit

Today I started to play around with git to create some patches. I choose egit for this job, because I don't know a nice gui for git and I'm a eclipse user. I created a branch and I changed the following files (result of git status)

```
   modified:   .gitignore
   modified:   framework/src/play/utils/Java.java
   modified:   modules/crud/app/controllers/CRUD.java
```

If I call commit on the project in eclipse I only get
       modified:   .gitignore
       modified:   framework/src/play/utils/Java.java
even a commit on the CRUD file himself doesn't help.

I'm using under debian lenny, eclipse 3.6.1 with egit 0.9.1. I haven't a problem working on the console except if I want to analyze diffs. 
It's a little bit frustrating. Never get such a trouble with bzr.

After change CRUD again (before commit) and call git add . CRUD wasn't added. I must do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.gitignore` support in `egit` is incomplete.
2. try `git add -A .`

Comment: ad 1: means that egit ignores files even if they are not in `.gitignore?` ad 2.: git version 1.5.6.5 hasn't `-A` as an option.